# Magento not calculating the shipping cost - Table rates (Basic setup)

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping-methods, table-rates

I am having huge problems getting Table Rates Shipping Method to calculate the shipping cost.

I´ve setup the Tables rates as follows (Norwegian translation):

```
Land,Fylke/stat,Postnummer,"Vekt (og over)",Leveringspris
NOR,*,*,0.0100,39.0000
NOR,*,*,0.3700,79.0000
```

and also set weight for each product, but the shipping cost always shows zero. That´ll say, no shipping cost is never calculated.

See this screenshot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/yeiel45lum11mca/Screenshot%202015-03-23%2010.20.11.png?dl=0

Any ideas on why this happen? I am very new to Magento so any help will be highly appreciated on this.

Answer (score 0):

Check you have actually set your Magento store to use this method for the country of origin that the customer puts in at the checkout for their address.

go to

System/configuration/
from the left menu select
Shipping methods/table rates

look at Ship to Applicable Countries check your settings here.

If you have specific countries selected make sure that the country that you selected in your checkout is actually selected in the list.

If you have all allowed countries selected here then go to

system/configuration/ General/ Countries Options and check to see that your Default Country is correct and that the allowed countries list has the correct countries selected.